# Is it possible to inflate a view that contains `FragmentContainerView` inside a `Fragment`?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm trying to inflate a view that contains `FragmentContainerView` inside a fragment that's being put into a layout.

- RootView

  - Fragment

    - CustomView

      - FragmentContainerView

Like this:

```
val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, Frag(), "tag");
transaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss()
```

where `Frag` creates a view that inflates a xml like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:parentTag="android.widget.FrameLayout">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</merge>
```

But when I execute the code, my app crashes:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

---

How can I avoid this error while using `FragmentContainerView` (obs.: if I use `<fragment>` instead of `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>`, everything works fine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always, always use `childFragmentManager` when nesting fragments - the `childFragmentManager` is never executing transactions when its parent is going through lifecycle changes (which I assume is when you're calling your transaction).

This is actually silently causing issues for you when you use the `<fragment>` tag as those lifecycle events don't actually occur as a transaction, but directly as part of inflation. Using the wrong `FragmentManager` means that the fragment and its views will not properly save and restore their state.

The reason it fails with `FragmentContainerView` is that `FragmentContainerView` actually does the same `FragmentTransaction` as you'd do normally.

Comment: Hi, @ianhanniballake. Thanks for the reply. I'll try to do that by adding the nested `nav_graph` fragment manually. Cheers \o/ (P.S.: a problem I was having with `<fragment>` when swapping between fragments was probably due to what you've pointed out [silently causing issues]. Thanks for the info)